# how to create partitioned table with liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Can I create partitioned table like:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30),
    borned TIMESTAMP)
PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(borned)) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00')),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

using liquibase tags? I mean not with custom `<sql>` but with `<createTable>`

Answer (score 12):

**Since 1.9:** You can use [`modifySql`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/modify_sql.html) to append to the [`createTable`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_table.html) output

```xml
<changeSet author="StackOverflow" id="C0FE77AA-5517-11E7-8CAD-224C16886A7C">
    <createTable tableName="test">
        <column name="id" type="INT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="NAME" type="VARCHAR(30)"/>
        <column name="borned" type="TIMESTAMP"/>
    </createTable>
    <modifySql dbms="postgresql">
        <append value=" PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(borned)) (
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00')),
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Liquibase outputs the following SQL (according to the `updateSql` goal):

```sql
CREATE TABLE db.test (id INT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(30) NULL, borned timestamp NULL) PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(borned)) (     PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00')),     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));
```

Comment: Can you please share me, How I can build the same in a yaml? (especially **modifySql** part).

Comment: If table is already created. How can i add "partition by"? with out deleting the existing table.

Comment: It seems to work only if the table and its columns have no comments

Answer (score 0):

Not without writing your own custom change tag (like [Datical](http://www.datical.com/) has done).

Comment: thanks, but it's not the reason to migrate to other db migration tool in a 3-years project)